# Search in belongsToMany-relation for item by pivot value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I got these models:

- `Order`
- `Invoice`

An `Order` can have many `Invoice`s and an `Invoice` can belong to many `Order`s.

Example:

Orders:

- Order #1
- Order #2
- Order #3

Invoices:

- Invoice #1 -> belongs To `Order #1` and `Order #2` (so this `Invoice` contains both `Order`s)
- Invoice #2 -> belongsTo  `Order #2` and `Order #3`

Each `belongsTo`-relation saves a `date` as pivot, which defines the last date this order has been invoiced.

Now I'd like to create a `isInvoiceable()` getter for my Order-Model, which returns, whether the order has been invoiced within the last month or not. If the latest `date` is older than one month, return `true`, as this Order should create a new invoice.

So now I need your help: I need to check all invoices, whether there's an `Order` (belongsToMany) with the `order_id` of the current `Order`, and a `date`-pivot that's older than now - one month. I need to check the `order_id` because the `Invoice` could possibly contain information about other `Order`s, too.

And this is the missing link for me: How can I check the `belongsToMany`-relation in `Invoice` for `date` and `order_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have defined your relation as 'invoices', you may do something like this:

```
class Order extends Model {

...


public function isInvoiceable(){
    $lastInvoiceDate = (date('Y-m-d', $this->invoices()->latest()->created_at));
    $today = new Carbon(date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Input::get('startdate'))));
    $diff_months = $lastInvoiceDate->diff($today)->months;

    return $diff_months < 1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, as the invoices can belong to multiple orders and the date is saved as pivot in the belongsToMany-relation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `wherePivot` method, which should do what you want.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

*Filtering Relationships Via Intermediate Table Columns:*

> You can also filter the results returned by belongsToMany using the
>   wherePivot, wherePivotIn, and wherePivotNotIn methods when defining
>   the relationship:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->wherePivot('approved', 1);

return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->wherePivotIn('priority', [1, 2]);

return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->wherePivotNotIn('priority', [1, 2]);
```

I have not tested it, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
public function isInvoiceable()
{
    // replace 'invoices()' with your relationship
    if ($this->invoices()->wherePivot('date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth())->count() > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices:

1- like  Remul said in his answer: using wherePivot();

2- using  [newPivotQuery()](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_newPivotQuery)

witch give you more space to work with ...

when you use this method, the query will be on pivot table directly ...

```
class Order extends Model {


public function isInvoiceable()
{

   return $this->invoices()-> newPivotQuery()->firstWhere('date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth())!=null;
}
```

the advantage of using newPivotQuery() that you can insert,update, make overall queries ...